# How to import the own model into myproject/alembic/env.py?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, alembic

I want to use `alembic revision --autogenerate` with my own model classes. Because of that I need to import them in `myproject/alembic/env.py` as [described in the docs](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html). But this doesn't work even if I tried a lot of variations.

I am not sure in which context (don't know if this is the correct word) does alembic run the `env.py`. Maybe that causes some errors.

This is the directory and file structure I use.

```
myproject/
    common/
        __init__.py
        model.py
    alembic/
        env.py
```

The error is kind of that

```
    from .common import model
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

`myproject` itself is just a repository/working directory. It is not *installed* into the system (with `pip3`, `apt-get`, `easyinstall` or anything else).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fiddling around few hours with this same issue, I found out a solution. First, this is my structure right now:

```
. ← That's the root directory of my project
├── alembic.ini
├── dev-requirements.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── src
│   └── models
│       ├── base.py
│       ...
│       └── migrations
│           ├── env.py
│           ├── README
│           ├── script.py.mako
│           └── versions
│          
└── tests
```

in `env.py` I simply did this:

```
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname
sys.path.insert(0, dirname(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))))) # Insert <.>/src
import models # now it can be imported
target_metadata = models.base.Base.metadata
```

Hope you find this useful! :)

**EDIT:** I then did my first revision with the database empty (with no tables yet), alembic filled everything automatically for `upgrade()` and `downgrade()`. I did that in this way because not all my tables were *automagically* detected by alembic.

Comment: Side Note: You will need to adjust your alembic.init `script_location` to your new migrations folder path

Answer (score 31):

You can set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to control what python sees as the top level folder, eg. if you are in the root folder of your project:

```
PYTHONPATH=. alembic revision -m "..."
```

Then you can use a "normal" import in your alembic env.py, relative to your root folder, in your example:

```
from src.models.base import Base
```

Comment: thanks, this is a simple answer to a maddening problem.

Comment: I feel like this should be in the Alembic docs and/or handled by alembic... pretty glaring issue with the default implementation...

Comment: I would prefer to solve this kind of issues in the code, not at runtime. Is @joe-heffer solution the recommended solution?

Answer (score 17):

Put this in your env.py to put the working directory onto the Python path:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I used `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` from this tutorial - 
https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/using-databases-python-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/

Answer (score 9):

For alembic 1.5.5 and above, add the following to your `alembic.ini`:

```
prepend_sys_path = .
```

From [alembic documentation](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html): this will be prepended to sys.path if present, defaults to the current working directory.

Comment: This is the best solution. My `alembic` folder is in the project root and by changing this path to `..` I can import models in `app/models.py`.

Comment: Great tip! 1.5.5 was released February 2021, so it's not fairly new. See https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/releases/tag/rel_1_5_5 .

Comment: this is the correct solution, i was referencing this SO post in a older repo from 2020 and then resetting up alembic in a new repo, i referenced this again, and was pleasantly surprised they added a built in feature to do this. leaving `prepend_sys_path` as the default for me worked , if alembic.ini is in the root folder of your project, alongside the folder that is your 'module' (so `<root>/alembic.ini` and `<root>/your_module_here/some_code.py` etc